how to fill entity with child entities when there is weak entity in middle
Users table:
public class User : BaseEntity
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }

    public List<Site> Sites { get; set; }
}

Site Table:
public class Site : BaseEntity
{
    public string SiteName{ get; set; }
}

UserSites table:
public class UserSite : BaseEntity
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string SiteId { get; set; }
}

Each user might have multiple sites, so how to model entity when I want all site entities inside a user object
var user = dbContext.User.Include("Site").FirstOrDefault();

I need all sites inside this user object but its null

In EF-terminology, this is a join entity, i.e. an entity that joins two entities in a many-to-many association. There are really lots of questions on how to populate many-to-many objects. You should be able to find them when knowing the terminology.
